# Firebase recyclerview always refreshes and losses its scroll position when starting new activity and returning

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

My Firebase recycler view always refreshes and loses its scroll position when opening new activity and coming back. Tried multiple solution in Stack Overflow but none woks for me. Here is my code

```
class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   private var layoutManager:RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
    private var recyclerViewState: Parcelable? = null
    private var recyclerView:RecyclerView? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu)
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView!!.layoutManager = layoutManager
}
override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        var productRef: DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child(PRODUCTS_DB_NAME).child(
            PRODUCT_STATE_ACTIVE)
        var options:FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Products>? = null
            options = FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Products>().setQuery(productRef, Products::class.java).
            setLifecycleOwner(this).build()
        val adapter = object : FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Products, ProductViewHolder>(options) {
            override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProductViewHolder {
                return ProductViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.product_items_layout, parent, false))
            }

            protected override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProductViewHolder, position: Int, model: Products) {
                holder.txtProductName.text = model.pname
                holder.txtProductDescription.text = model.description
                holder.txtProductPrice.text = "Price = ₹ " + model.price.toString()
                val context = holder.itemView.context
                Picasso.with(this@HomeActivity).load(model.image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(holder.imageView,
                    object: Callback {
                        override fun onSuccess() {
                        }

                        override fun onError() {
                            Picasso.with(this@HomeActivity).load(model.image).into(holder.imageView)
                        }
                    })
                holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
                    val intent:Intent = Intent(this@HomeActivity, ProductDetailsActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("pid", model.pid)
                    startActivity(intent)
                }
            }
        }
        val recyclerView:RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_menu)
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
        adapter.startListening()
    }
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        recyclerViewState = recyclerView!!.getLayoutManager()!!.onSaveInstanceState();

    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        recyclerView!!.getLayoutManager()!!.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
    }
    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        recyclerView!!.getLayoutManager()!!.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this method in my code check it

```
 private fun updateRecycler(){
    val recyclerViewState = recyclerView.layoutManager?.onSaveInstanceState()
    recyclerView.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    recyclerView.layoutManager?.onRestoreInstanceState(recyclerViewState)
}
```

I see you use this method when you update data

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
```

That is bad idea. you must set adapter once and change data every time. you need rethink on your code

Comment: From where above function should be called?

Comment: @Rajesh when you change data of adapter and need to refresh

Comment: Unfortunately  I am a newbie. I am not changing data of adapter. Basically followed example like this: https://grokonez.com/android/kotlin-firebase-realtime-database-display-list-data-kotlin-firebaserecycleradapter-example-android

Comment: Please let me know what you want me to change and try. I am setting adapter once in onStart, also tried moving everything from onStart to onCreate as well and still no effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to save your state of recycler view scroll view, if you want to achieve what you want here.

**Save state of recyclerview scrollView**

**1. Make a variable**

```
private Parcelable scroll_state;
```

**2. save state in onPause()**

```
scroll_state = linearLayoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
```

**3. restore state in onResume()**

```
linearLayoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(scroll_state);
```

Note : Here, linearlayoutmanager is the layoutmanager of your recyclerview.

Comment: No, unfortunately not working. Always losses scroll position and refreshing

Comment: Because you are setting adapter wrong. Try to move out your recyclerview set adapter code in OnStart() , then it will working fine.

Comment: -where should I move set adapter code from I start? To which method I should move this code to?

Comment: tried moving everything in onStart to onCreate still same. When first time I click on the product and then come back then I can see the same product at its place(which I want) but when I scroll and click on next product and when I come back that product shift down and basically recycler view is refreshed and scroll position is different

Answer (score 0):

**I solved my problem with a simpler solution.**

I just called adapter.startListening(); in onViewCreated() instead of onStart and called adapter.stopListening(); in onDestroyView() instead of onStop()
That prevented the entire list from regenerating while coming back from the next activity and thus retained the scroll position where it was previously.

for more details please visit: https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/998#issuecomment-342413662